# Is strtok_r() part of string.h or not

Tags: c, strtok

Folks, I've been using my own implementation of strtok_r() in a project for some time and thought I'd align the declaration to the standard implementation, purely for neatness.

However, the few sites I'd usually quickly check such things on didn't list it as part of string.h, so looked further afield. Other sites *do* list it as part of the standard string.h,  *but have different declarations for it*

So is it or isn't it? Is there an authoritative reference either way? Thanks.

EDIT: maybe it's POSIX?

Comment: it is obvious that it is not a standard C function.

Comment: Yes, it's included in POSIX (from first version) but not in C and it's declared as `char* strtok_r(char* str, const char* delim, char** saveptr);`

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti You're missing the `restrict` modifiers.

Comment: @Barmar you're right, not only compilers are slow to fully support C99...also myself!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's POSIX, not standard C. If you check the [POSIX spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strtok_r.html) you'll see that it's marked with [[CX]](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/help/codes.html#CX), which indicates that it's an extension to the C standard. You can also find the official prototype there:

```
char *strtok_r(char *restrict s, const char *restrict sep,
   char **restrict lasts);
```

If you're seeing different declarations, it may be that some of them haven't incorporated the `restrict` keywords, which were added in Issue 6.